# GWT front-end and back-end separation & shared objects

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, bean-validation

I have an application consisting of two eclipse projects:

- A back-end with processing and connectors to Google Sheets to load and store data
- A Web-application providing Webservices consumed by a GWT front-end

The back-end can also be used by standalone applications. The back-end should not have any dependencies to the front-end.

Now I don't know where to place certain objects such as DTOs and custom constraint validators without duplication:

- DTOs are generated by the back-end, served by the webservice and displayed and edited in the GWT front-end.
- Ideally, bean validators, including custom validators should be coded once and used in all three tiers for input validation
- In the back-end, DTOs contain code that is not translatable to Javascript (translation from and to Google Sheets objects)
- The back-end should not have any dependencies to the front-end, so placing the code in the "shared" path of the GWT application is not an option

Is it possible to define classes (validators and DTO) in the backend and use them in the front-end, given these circumstances?

Comment: Why can't you put your DTO's and validators in the shared package ? 
You can create a shared maven project that contains those shared resources and both backend and frontend have a dependency on it. This way the backend doesn't depend on the frontend and vice versa.

Comment: How do I tell the GWT compiler to look in the different project? The "source" paths in the gwt.xml are relative to the location of the gwt.xml file.  Should I create a GWT module with the DTO and validators?

Comment: Yes you can pass additional sources to the GWT compiler. But I would recommend to have a look at Thomas Broyer's GWT multi [maven archetypes](https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes) and [maven plugin](https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-plugin).